# How to embed a common lisp interpreter into a gui application

Tags: user-interface, lisp, common-lisp

I want to know how to embed a lisp interpreter into a gui application, i.e. something like what pyshell does for Python.

Comment: why an interpreter? how about a Lisp compiler?

Comment: jrockway, I'm not sure if your comment really answers the question. For a real command interpreter one would need more than that. See for example the CLIM listener providing input editing, error handling, etc.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Some options:

1. **Write the complete application including the GUI in Lisp**: lots of Lisp systems support that
2. **Write the application in Lisp and link C code to it, if you need to call some external GUI libraries**: Lisp systems can load and call C (and compatible) libraries.
3. **Embed Lisp into your application**: [ECL](http://ecls.sourceforge.net/) (Embeddable Common Lisp) is an obvious choice. LispWorks (commercial) and Allegro CL (commercial) can deliver Lisp code as shared libraries. You can then load such a shared library into your program.

Answer (score 0):

I've had success with [GNU Guile](http://www.gnu.org/s/guile/), if you're OK with Scheme instead of Common Lisp